# increasing font weight of my cufon font

Tags: wordpress, fonts, cufon

For my Wordpress website, I have added the cufon plugin and uploaded my font. The code (shown below) is what I put in the cufon plugin box to have my uploaded font show. The font is quite faint and there is no "bold" version of the font. I would really appreciate help for the following that I just can't figure out:

1. Increasing the font weight of the font or making it bold.
2. Replacing my navbar menu font with this Gruppo font (I'm not sure the replacement code for changing it)

   Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'Gruppo').replace('#content');

Answer (score 1):

You would have to access the stylesheet of your theme and just find the block referring to the nav-bar styles and switch out the font right there. Make sure you know what you're looking for (e.g. class name or id name for the specific nav-bar). Something like this:

```
.nav-bar-style{
font-family: 'Gruppo';
}
```

You can get to your style.css right from the editor under Appearance tab or if you are in ftp you can just go into the file by navigating to it. Usually the path would look like

```
domain.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/style.css (or .../THEMENAME/styles/style.css)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the boldness issue, only the font itself can provide a browser with a bold version of itself.  If the font in question has no bold characters, then it seems to me that you have only the following 2 options:

1) choose another font, this time one with bold characters

2) use the CSS text-shadow property to provide the characters with enough text shadow to look a bit darker, e.g.,

```
nav-bar {
  font-family: 'Gruppo';
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 black;
}
```

I'm not sure that this second option will make a dramatic difference, and it might make some letters look weird, but it's easy enough to try.